# Does my system has any potential Malware as Chrome is showing "This page has insecure content" pop-up

Tags: google-chrome, virus, malware, spyware, phishing

Well, I've been using chrome for a long time and it never showed such message unless it actually is.

Actually, I had to crack a RAR file for that I searched over google and found some tools which I thought would work. So, I installed one of them. Later I uninstalled as I found them to be useless.

So, what I observed is that, after un-installation, chrome started showing this message when ever I open any new website including Google.com, Facebook.com.. almost any website.

`This page has insecure content - Don't load(recommended) , Load anyway`

I am worried whether any un-wanted phishing tools were hiding in my browser!! I re-installed chrome but the situation is same.

I tried to edit "options" but couldn't do anything as they were perfect. I even don't store my passwords in chrome...

Why this is happening? anything wrong with my browser? any malware is on my PC?

**Update**

Some of you have suggested to run anti-malware softwares but I thought they are too time consuming. So, instead of that I "restored" my system using system restore utility. Now, chrome isn't showing any such pop-ups.

Now as to cross check, I used Microsoft Safety Scanner and it showed me a infected file at System32 folder, `Trojan:Win32/Neop` which I removed...

**can I now assume that there isn't any malware/ spyware on my system?**

Comment: Please dont pirate...

Comment: [You're welcome...](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now).

Comment: This might [help](http://www.lockergnome.com/net/2011/11/30/how-to-disable-this-page-has-insecure-content-warning-in-chrome/).

Comment: Ahmed... turning off the warning doesn't make him any safer.

Comment: Does a system restore would do the job instead of using anti malware tools??

Comment: @Surya - Nope.  The system restore also didn't get rid of the infection.  Considering he removed the infection after he did one.  Of course the warning itself isn't the reason he was infered, he downloaded tools from websites in the darkest part of the web, that is the reason he was infected plus the fact he doesn't use the right type of security.

Comment: **can I now assume that there isn't any malware/ spyware on my system?** You cannot assume anything format the hdd then reinstall the operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have websites that use `https` connections, and some of the content inside the page comes from non-https sites (basic http), you'll see that warning.

Many sites today are switching to https by default, meaning everything will be encrypted between their servers and you.  Unfortunately many 3rd party apps (like games in facebook) still rely on basic http requests to their servers in order to pull some data.  So basically the page is only "partially-secure" ... with the potential of not being even slightly secure.

Many times you can simply ignore the message and press on... just keep in mind that some of the content is sent/received without ANY encryption... and potentially even data that was sent securely could be re-transmitted insecurely.

Potentially virii on your computer could also be proxying traffic in your web-browser and putting advertisements/scripts/etc on pages that under normal situations would have none.

Comment: I would put the "potentially" at the top of your post. Don't encourage him to click through it. The thing is he didn't used to get these warnings, now he gets them on every SSL enabled page.

Comment: No doubt.  But I tried to keep the answer generic enough for other visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have a virus that is injecting code into every page you view. The elements that the code injects reside on a site other than Facebook (for example), which is why you're suddenly getting warnings that some elements are insecure.

You have malware. [See this page for removal instructions.](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now/157533#157533)

Comment: I use Microsoft Security Essentials and it didn't show any such threat.

Comment: Would a system restore would work? Actually I don't want to mess up and waste my time with those tools. So, I restored my system and now, its working fine.. Its not asking!. now, my system have any malware??

Comment: It's hard to know for certain. It would appear that THAT malware has probably been deactivated, but there could be others. It's not an answer people like to hear, but the only way to be * positively sure * that you don't have a malware infestation is to wipe everything and start clean. That said, you could assuage your fears by running some of the tools in that post that MOAB thoughtfully added. I would run at least Malwarebytes. This may sound time consuming, but you know what's more time consuming? Dealing with Google because your email password has been stolen.

Comment: Well, I would re-install Windows7 but should I clean up the whole HDD or just the drive in which I installed Win7 (my case, its C

Comment: How is using anti-malware software a waste of time but spending hours reinstalling an operating system and backing up your system isn't.  As your question was updated, clearly YOU WERE infected, which goes to show your system restore was sort of useless.

Answer (score -1):

in this moment the message could be related with a very recent update of Chrome http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/jUtdQTLYK8c

Comment: The message describe is different and thus has nothing to do with the author's problem ( malware ).

Comment: 1) the message is exactly the same 2) could be related with "malware" in the case of the author´s problem, but in this moment, exactly the same message could be related with the last update of Chrome that was the previous week. I search the message of Chrome on google and I found this question. I think that my answer will be useful for the same message of Chrome.

Comment: the cause indicated by TheCompWiz is similar of the cause reported on  http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/jUtdQTLYK8c (but talks are related with the last update of Chorme).